# Problema con Android SDK en Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, sdk

!Buenas!

Estoy intentando acceder a **Android SDK Manager** en Visual Studio, para Xamarin.

Cuando intento ejecutarlo, me aparece una ventana diciéndome:

> No se encuentra adb.exe en la ruta de acceso de SDK especificada

Esta es la ruta donde debe de estar en teoría:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

He ido a revisar que este **adb.exe** este en la carpeta, pero no es asi. Si voy a la ruta especificada, no hay nada al respecto. He intentado buscar alguna forma de instalar o reinstalar esto, pero no encuentro nada que me ayude.

**¿Como podría solucionarlo?**

Comment: Revisa si se encuentra dentro de : C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools , si no es así debes instalar "Plaform Tools".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El archivo `adb.exe`  se debe encontrar dentro del directorio `/platform-tools` del sdk, posiblemente no lo tenga instalado, en tu caso el archivo se debería encontrar en la ruta:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

Si no se encuentra instalado debes proceder a la instalación de "`Android SDK Plaform-Tools`".

---

**Visual Studio Xamarin**.

Ve a "Android SDK Manager" :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y descarga:

[image: <code>SDK Platform-tools</code>]

Revisa **[Configuración del SDK de Android para Xamarin.Android](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows)**

---

**Android Studio**

Ve al menú selecciona `Tools` > `SDK Manager` y selecciona la sección `SDK Tools`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aquí es donde no puedo acceder: **Android SDK Manager** en Visual Studio. En cambio, desde Android Studio, si me funciona y me indica que esta instalado. He copiado la ruta que me indica en Android Studio y la he copiado en Visual, pero aun así nada.

Comment: @Youshiro ohh por lo que comentas me parece que no tienes instalado el Android SDK Manager , ve a Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings:, ¿ tienes definido Android SDK location?, si es asi revisa si dentro tienes platform-tools.

Comment: Vale, ya esta todo perfecto. Ya me ha reconocido la ruta. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Youshiro excelente, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalarlo desde:

Tools -> SDK Manager

Se te desplegara la siguiente pantalla. Seleccionas SDK Tools y lo instalas

[image: sdk tools]

Nota: No recuerdo si existe una versión en español